# Is there a way to make Photoshop CS6 work with touchscreen monitors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs6

I have a 15.6" touchscreen laptop and I would like to be able to use the touchscreen in Photoshop. It works fine in Illustrator but for some reason Adobe didn't make Photoshop compatible with touch screens.

Does anyone know a way to make Photoshop CS6 work with touchscreen monitors?

It's so frustrating not being able to use touchscreen in Photoshop, especially now that I'm getting used to using it in Illustrator. Not to mention every other program I've tried works with it no problem.

My laptop is an Asus Q500A 15.6" Touchscreen Laptop.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, touch screens are not supported in CS6.

I found a couple of positive ideas, though! One in this [Adobe Community thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4949360):

> In order to draw with my finger or a pen, I need to select outside of
>   the boundary of the canvas and drag inorder to draw.

So might be worth a try. The answer to that question mentions compatibility issues between APIs, and says that a 'poor' driver had been created for the N-tig hardware that uses the other API, however it wasn't working well (I couldn't find it, will keep looking).

This [other thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4755258) also mentions a possible hack:

> This is a bit awkward, but until I find a real solution, this works
>   just fine: when you want to use the touch screen for CS6, hold down
>   the mouse button. You may have to use the mouse to tap the tools you
>   want, but at least there's a temporary solution.

Also, I don't see this as off-topic. We have plenty of questions about tablet compatibility. It might not be exactly 'graphic design', but it's still in scope according to our question history.

Answer (score 1):

As for holding the mouse button you have to start tracing with your stylus or finger and then click the mouse button while you continue to move. Awkward at best.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what type of laptop you have but have you looked into [Adobe Photoshop Touch](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-touch.html)?  It does interact with a few tablets and small devices.  I haven't used Touch but heard about it.  I know there is a tablet that can run Photoshop but I will have to find more info.  It's not a full blown version of Photoshop but it does have pressure sensitive brush features.

Answer (score 0):

it's a temporary solution, but I already use every photoshop version.
photoshop cs4 support touch screen laptop, i don't know the older version work or not. but the newest version exactly won't support with my laptop (asus tp500l).
Try it. it's work perfectly to me. i found the solution 15 minutes before i post this solution.

double tap and drag, if i just tap once and move my finger it wont draw any

glad to wait for another solution